# Yii2 передача значения в модуль

Tags: php, yii2, модули

Всем привет.

Возникла вот такая вот диллема:
В модуле есть `public $email = 'test@test.test'`

В config/main я подключаю данный модуль, но не меняю в конфигах это значение, дальше, в нужной мне вьюхе происходит такой код:

```
$email = "myEmail@email.email";
$myModule = \Yii::$app->getModule('myModName');
$myModule->email = $email;
```

На стороне модуля есть контроллер с вот таким кусочком кода:

```
Yii::$app->mailer........->setTo($this->module->email)->......
```

**Суть проблемы:**
У меня как был на входе test@test.test email ,так и остается таким на контроллере, хотя я вроде-бы выше поменял значение свойства.

В чём я не прав, что контроллер модуля в итоге не видит новое значение?

Comment: Код контроллера из модуля выполняется сразу после изменения $email во вьюхе? Или до или в другом запросе? Поподробнее пожалуйста что за чем вызывается. Что за контроллер модуля что за вьюха?

Comment: @AntonRybalko  Выполняется в другом запросе: На фронте есть просто вьюха, где я инициализирую модуль ==> он отрисовывает форму, и AJAX запросом отправляет данные на свой SaveController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта строка меняет `emial` только для текущего экземпляра модуля в текущем запросе

```
$myModule->email = $email;
```

Нужно в представлении добавить email в форму (например, скрытый input) и явно передавать `email` AJAX-запросом в `SaveController`